# Get different results for the same expression in C#

Tags: c#

I am getting different results when changing from `!= true` to `== false` which I thought is exactly the same.

This is my code

```
User user = await GetUser(id);

if (user == null || user.Orders?.Any() != true)
{
    ...
}
```

If I change to `user.Orders?.Any() == true` some of my tests return different data. Why?

Comment: is ```user.Orders``` null?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `user.Orders?.Any()` have `bool?` type, because of '?' after Orders.
So if `user.Orders` is `null`, then result of `user.Orders?.Any()` will be `null` and `== true` will be false, while `!= false` will be true